# Starting azure VM in parallel and validate after in PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell

Context : I am automating starting of 3 Azure VM through a PowerShell script, and each VM is taking 4-5min to start. I want to run the start command parallel and after 5-6min verify them whether they are started.

```
function restartLoadAgents ($AzuresecretValue,$AzureApplicationID,$AzureObjectID,$AzureDirectoryID,$AzureUserName,$AzureSubscriptionID) {
        
        $password =  ConvertTo-SecureString $AzuresecretValue -AsPlainText -Force; 
        $LoadAgentResourceGroup = "test-performance-rg01";

        #Connecting to the Azure VM using the Service Principle
        $pscredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($AzureApplicationID, $password);
        Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $AzureDirectoryID -Credential $pscredential | Out-null;
        
        #List all the Load Agents
        $VMList = Get-AzVm -ResourceGroupName $LoadAgentResourceGroup -Status;

        ForEach($VM in $VMList) {

            #Skipping the Master Machine and DB machine
            if ($VM.Name -eq "test-load-appmachine01" -or $VM.Name -eq "test-load-appmachine02") {
                continue;
            }
            $VMLoadAgentStatus = (Get-AzVm -ResourceGroupName $LoadAgentResourceGroup -Name $VM.Name  -status).Statuses
            $CurrentLoadAgentRunningStatus = $VMLoadAgentStatus[1].DisplayStatus;
                
                if($CurrentLoadAgentRunningStatus -match "deallocated" -or $CurrentLoadAgentRunningStatus -match "VM deallocated"){
                        Start-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $LoadAgentResourceGroup -Name $VM.Name | Out-null
                        commandVerifier;  
                        checkVMStatus($VM.Name);                        
                }
                else {
                    Write-Host $VM.Name " Current State is "$CurrentLoadAgentRunningStatus;
                }
        }

}

function commandVerifier() {
        if ($?){
             Write-Host "Successfully Started "$VM.Name;
            }
        else {
             Write-Host "Start Unsuccessful "$VM.Name;
            }
}

function checkVMStatus($VM_NAME) {
        $VMLoadAgentStatus = (Get-AzVm -ResourceGroupName $LoadAgentResourceGroup -Name $$VM_NAME  -status).Statuses
        $VMRunningStatusAfterTriggered = $VMLoadAgentStatus[1].DisplayStatus;
                if($VMRunningStatusAfterTriggered -eq "running" -or $VMRunningStatusAfterTriggered -eq "VM running"){
                    Write-Host "Successfully Started VM"
                }
                else{
                    Write-Host "Something went with starting VM and current status is"$VMRunningStatusAfterTriggered
                }
}

function getServicePrincipleDetails () {
        $AzuresecretValue    = "<secretValue>";
        $AzureApplicationID  = "<app_id>";
        $AzureObjectID       = "<obj_id>";
        $AzureDirectoryID    = "<dir_id>";
        $AzureUserName       = "SVCUSER";
        $AzureSubscriptionID = "<sub_id>";
        restartLoadAgents $AzuresecretValue $AzureApplicationID $AzureObjectID $AzureDirectoryID $AzureUserName $AzureSubscriptionID

}

getServicePrincipleDetails
```

There are 5 VM in total and first two need not to be `stopped` or `started`. `test-load-appmachine03`,`test-load-appmachine04` & `test-load-appmachine05` are the target VM and I want to start them parallelly and check after.

Comment: You can start reading the [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-7.2) cmdlet.

Comment: you can also try implementing you solution using either of foreach -parallel (if you are using [PowerShell 5.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psworkflow/about/about_foreach-parallel?view=powershell-5.1)) or foreach-object -parallel ( if you are using [PowerShell 7.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/))